# How to mock os.walk in python with a temporary filesystem using monkeypatching(PyTest)?

Tags: python, operating-system, pytest, os.walk

I have a function that uses `os.walk` and I want to test it using monkeypatching (PyTest). I don't know how to use `monkeypatch.setattr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve correct mock of the os.walk, you have to use

```
monkeypatch.setattr(os, "walk", function_that_will_simulate_os_walk_iterator)
```

The  `function_that_will_simulate_os_walk_iterator` should return a list of tuples `(root, dirs, files)` for each simulated file.

Comment: Is this good?
`
def mockreturn(path):
 return_value = [
  ('/foo', ('bar',), ('baz',)),
  ('/foo/bar', (), ('spam', 'eggs')),
 ]
 return return_value
monkeypatch.setattr(os, 'walk', mockreturn) 
`